# Recommended bit-rate value for x264 1st pass

Tags: bitrate, x264

I use x264 to encode content for an Adaptive Bit-Rate workflow.

So I run a 1st pass to find the "optimal"GOP structure (but with a `--keyint` target value) to a given bit-rate `X`.

And next I run different 2nd pass encoding using the statistic file (coming from the 1st pas) to generate encoding (different bit-rate and resolution) with the same GOP structure - it's a requirement for ABR streaming.

My question is: Depending of the different bit-rate I use in the second pass, what will be the best choice for bit-rate parameter of the 1st pass **to optimize the video quality of all 2nd pass encoding** ? Should I use the min or the max bit-rate, or a median value ?

Comment: see my edit, as the stat file contain a lot of info, and I suspect that some of them are `bit-rate` dependent, I would like to know if there is a `de-facto` rule we can use to select the 1s pass bit-rate, if we know the target bit-rate we will use for the 2nd pass !